# trouble getting converse.js to run

Tags: converse.js

I'm trying to run converse.js on my system.
I've configured the xmpp server (prosody) and verified that the bosh service works as it should.
Now when I try to invoke it from chrome, I get the following error:

> converse.js:39566  FATAL: Error: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on
>   'Node': Only one element on document allowed.
>       at child._ensureElement (https://cdn.conversejs.org/dist/converse.js:42192:32)
>       at child.Backbone.View (https://cdn.conversejs.org/dist/converse.js:38271:10)
>       at child.constructor (https://cdn.conversejs.org/dist/converse.js:39035:21)
>       at child.Backbone.Overview (https://cdn.conversejs.org/dist/converse.js:41669:10)
>       at new child (https://cdn.conversejs.org/dist/converse.js:38932:41)
>       at Object. (https://cdn.conversejs.org/dist/converse.js:42252:34)
>       at triggerEvents (https://cdn.conversejs.org/dist/converse.js:37416:57)
>       at triggerApi (https://cdn.conversejs.org/dist/converse.js:37404:19)
>       at eventsApi (https://cdn.conversejs.org/dist/converse.js:37203:16)
>       at Object.Events.trigger (https://cdn.conversejs.org/dist/converse.js:37394:5)

Does anyone have an idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: as stated in the documentation, a  part is required in the html-code.